# Repeated Identifiers in a Single Var Declaration in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5, google-closure-compiler

I have noticed that **Google's Closer Compiler** may pack statements with variables into a preceding `var` declaration producing repeated identifiers in that declaration. This is an example of the output I got:

```
    var a = Ak - Aj, 
        b = Bk - Bj, 
        c = Math.sqrt(a*a+b*b), 
        a = a / c,
        b = b / c
```

Notice how `a` and `b` are re-declared and assigned new values within the same `var` declaration. Additionally, it looks like the old values of `a` and `b` are used in their second initialization. Does this produce a well defined behavior in **ES5 / ES6**?

Comment: Duplicate `var` declarations of the same variable are allowed, they're treated as assignments. You wouldn't be able to do the same thing with `let`, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The EcmaScript specification has this in the [section on `var`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-variable-statement):

> A `var` statement declares variables that are scoped to the running execution context's VariableEnvironment. Var variables are created when their containing Lexical Environment is instantiated and are initialized to **undefined** when created. Within the scope of any VariableEnvironment a common *BindingIdentifier* may appear in more than one *VariableDeclaration* but those declarations collectively define only one variable. A variable defined by a *VariableDeclaration* with an *Initializer* is assigned the value of its *Initializer*'s *AssignmentExpression* when the *VariableDeclaration* is executed, not when the variable is created.

In other words, a variable may occur more than once in a `var` statement, but the concerned variable will still only be declared once, and that declaration will happen before any code (in that scope) is executed (a.k.a. "hoisting"). The initialisations will be executed in their normal execution order.

So, by specification, your example code is equivalent to:

```
var a, b, c;
a = Ak - Aj;
b = Bk - Bj; 
c = Math.sqrt(a*a+b*b); 
a = a / c;
b = b / c;
```